# No module named 'debug_toolbar.urls' : version 3.1.1 installed

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'debug_toolbar',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', 
   )
```

urls.py

```
if DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += url('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls'))
```

requirements.txt

```
Django
django-debug-toolbar==3.1.1
```

its showing No module named 'debug_toolbar.urls' when testing on the server.

Comment: https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#check-for-prerequisites are those fulfilled?

Comment: yes @hanspeters205

Comment: did you  made the import **import debug_toolbar**

Comment: yes ...in urls.py file...like shown above. Also tried putting it at top... didnt work

Comment: Have you installed the package? Do you see it listed after a `pip list` at the respective environment?

Comment: yes...pip freeze gives me the version mentioned above in requirements.txt file

Comment: path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')), i added this and its working

Answer (score 0):

You are using an ancient version of Django Debug Toolbar. The `urls` module was added in [v3.2.3](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id9). Install the latest version and it will work. You can also remove the direct module import (`import debug_toolbar`) since it is no longer required.